# delete the first line of a .txt file with R

Tags: r

I have a lot of very large `txt-files` that have a header I would like to remove.
Is there a way to do this without reading in the entire file?
Possibly using the `system()` command?
I found some ideas [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96226/delete-first-line-of-a-file) but I haven't been able to make them work. I am using Windows 7 and R Version 3.2.2.

Here is what I have tried:

```
> systCommand <- paste0("echo '$(tail -n +2 ",  myFilePath, ")' > ", myFilePath)
> system(systCommand, intern=T)
Error in system(systCommand, intern = T) : 'echo' not found
```

I am pretty sure that this is because I am using windows?

Comment: If I may ask - why do you want remove header in the first place?

Answer (score -3):

after reading in

```
count_table <- read.table("your path/filename.txt")
head(count_table)
```

if the first row is header,

```
c_table <- count_table[-1,]
head(c_table)
```

then, the first line of header can be removed

Comment: I would like to avoid reading in the entire file.. This does not help.